# Grep and regex, match with a word, blank space and double digits

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

I started manipulating regular expressions and wish to know what I'm doing wrong here.

My purpose is to search within a file, the match equivalent to the following description :

> The word "lignes" may be followed by a blank space and two digits which range between 0 and 9.

When I do this :

`grep -ic -e "lignes[[:blank:]][0-9][0-9]" exemples-grep.txt` I get 2 matches.

Wishing to take into account the probability of having a space or not I added a `?` and also wanting to factorize it better, I wrote:

`grep -ic -e "lignes[[:blank:]]?[0-9]{2} exemples-grep.txt` it shows 0 matches.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: try `grep -ic -e "lignes[[:blank:]]{0,1}[0-9]{2} exemples-grep.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to either escape the `?` as in default basic regular expressions (BREs) `?` is matched as literal `?`. Otherwise you can use `-E` (extended regex) option.

See these examples:

```
grep -ic "lignes[[:blank:]]?[0-9][0-9]" <<< 'lignes 12'
0

grep -ic "lignes[[:blank:]]\?[0-9][0-9]" <<< 'lignes 12'
1

grep -Eic "lignes[[:blank:]]?[0-9][0-9]" <<< 'lignes 12'
1
```

Comment: This actually worked : `grep -ic -e "ligne[[:blank:]]\?[0-9]\{2\}" exemples_grep.txt`